# php mysql + ajax and jquery to dpopulate dynamic drop list

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, drop-down-menu

i am creating 2 dynamic drop list that the second one is based on the selection of the first  but the problem is that the second one do not populate  and i do not know where is the error can anyone help me ????

## dbconfig.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "*****";
$password = "****";
$db = "lam_el_chamel_db";
?>
```

## select.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#governorate").change(function(){
            $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#district").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_district.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#district").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#district").html(data);
            });
        });
        $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
            var cat = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
            var type = $("select#district option:selected").attr('value');
            if(cat>0 && type>0)
            {
                var result = $("select#district option:selected").html();
                $("#result").html('your choice: '+result);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
        <form id="select_form">
            Choose a governorate:<br />
            <select id="governorate">

            <?php echo $opt->ShowGovernorate(); ?>


            </select>
            <br /><br />

           choose a district:<br />
            <select id="type">
                <option value="0">choose...</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="confirm" />
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## select class.php

```
<?php 
 class SelectList
{
    protected $conn;

        public function __construct()

        {
           $this->DbConnect();
        }
    protected function DbConnect()
   {
    include "dbconfig.php";
    $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
    mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
    return TRUE;
   }  

    public function ShowGovernorate()
    {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM governorate";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $governorate = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $governorate .= '<option value="' . $row['governorate_id'] . '">' . $row['governorate_name'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $governorate;

    }
    public function ShowDistrict()
   {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM districts WHERE governorate_id=$_POST[id]";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
    $district = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
      {
        $district .= '<option value="' . $row['district_id'] . '">' . $row['district_name'] . '</option>';
      }
    return $district;
   }

}   
$opt = new SelectList(); 


?>
```

## select _type.php

```
<?php
include "select.class.php";
echo $opt->ShowDistrict();
?>
```

## table structure

governorate :

- governorate_id
- governorate_name

districts:

- district_id,
- district_name,
- governorate_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On select.php Page you used id for select tag is 'id="type"' which would be 'id = "district"' in select tag for choose a district : below text.

```
choose a district:<br />
<select id="type">
    <option value="0">choose...</option>
 </select>
```

By Below

```
choose a district:<br />
<select id="district">
   <option value="0">choose...</option>
</select>
```

Rename page 'select_type.php' by 'select_district.php' Or do change in $.post ajax query. correct sending request page name by 'select_type.php'.

Comment: i did change the type thanks for the help but this did not work

Comment: Ohh, You are sending request on 'select_district.php' but it should be 'select _type.php'. And on that before you were using '$_POST['id']' in query it was correct. Because in ajax call you are sending value in 'id' parameter so that no need to change '$_POST['governorate']' variable. Please, do as it is back that query. OR rename 'select_type.php' by 'select_district.php' page name

Comment: @ kishan patel thank you  for you comments i work perfect you saved me i was asking this question so  so many times thank youuuu

Comment: do you have any idea how to develop a comment system  that allow users to write comments and delete it ??

Answer (score 0):

This should be changed in

from `$sql = "SELECT * FROM districts WHERE governorate_id=$_POST[id]";`

to `$sql = "SELECT * FROM districts WHERE governorate_id=$_POST['governorate']";`

also in select.php change

```
<select id='governorate'> to <select id='governorate' name='governorate'>
```

Comment: did not  work it make the second drop list disable no matter what i choose